# How Salesforce gets sensor data from devices and using which protocol? MQTT?

Tags: iot

I am wondering in what format Salesforce receives sensor data? I heard IoT gateways capable of sending data to the cloud using MQTT protocol. Is Salesforce have the ability to understand the data from MQTT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce IoT uses platform events to accept streaming event data.

You can see this in [TrailHead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/iot_explorer_basics/iot_explorer_basics_unit_1_get_to_know) or in the [official doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=iotx_context_create.htm&type=5)